# Using the metadata api to Deploy actionOverrides on a Standard Object

Tags: metadata-api

I am trying to do as the title says and deploy an actionOverride using the metadata api. I have read everything in the developer guide (there isn't much). Has anyone had any success deploying actionOverrides on **standard objects**. I don't have an issue with Custom Objects.

Comment: No, I've had the same problem, where I couldn't find any elements associated with action overrides in the metadata xml that i pulled down using the ide. I've had to do it as a manual step to deploy it into each environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had a look at this for you Daniel. Few postings of a similar nature around, such as this [one](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/ActionOverrides-not-retrieved-for-Standard-Object-in-v18/td-p/172016). Sometimes such things are available as so call metadata subcomponents. But no joy here either (ActionOverride does not extend MetadataBase). Finally nor do I see it in the component types available when adding components to packages.

The [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/actionoverride.htm) do state it is only available for (and within) Custom Objects, but then as we know this data type in the WS schema is reused for Standard Objects as well, so again disappointing. Sorry but I think I'm concluding this is not possible.

> Action overrides are defined as part of a custom object.

Comment: For somebody bumping into this: Now it is possible to deploy action overrides for both custom and standard objects as stated in docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm